# How to handle poster misrepresenting commenter in post

Tags: discussion

I made a comment on an [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/75903/929). The person has quoted my comment into her answer in a dismissive way (and out of context) and introduced some meta-discussion about how men cannot understand the biases that women face and therefore it must be men voting the answer down.

I feel that the answer currently implies men in general, and I in particular, are dismissive of bias against women.  I find this offensive (and anyone who reads my twitter feed or attends faculty meetings with me would find this accusation surprising).  I could go into a long list of discussions I've had where I've argued the bias against women is significant and hard to eliminate without taking proactive steps.

I've asked the poster to remove my name and/or include the context of my statement, but she has explicitly refused.

I realize that it's incredibly frowned upon to edit the answer in a way that the answerer disagrees with, but I strongly object to the way I am presented in the answer.  Is there a point that it's acceptable to remove the discussion of me from someone else's answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the perfect way. Ask about it on meta or chat or flag for moderatorattention. Ideally providing a link so people can find it. Having a 3rd person take care of it reduces the chance of a fight.

I have edited out your name from the answer in question while leaving the example in place. While giving "credit" is desirable in general, this is clearly a case you did not want to be quoted like that.